# How to properly store additional info per form field and retrieve it with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I need to create a pdf file with a form and parse that form using c# and iTextSharp. So, if i create for example: a textbox, I'm giving it an id like text_12 and for additional info i create another hidden textbox and give it an id: lbl_12_title_someInfo_moreInfo etc..where 12 is the unique id..  which later I parse using c# and iTextSharp, but it doesn't look like the way to do it..
I need to create a textbox and store additional info in and later get the field by name and retrieve the additional info from it. How can I do that?
I tried to store a default value for the textbox but could not read it whatever i tried!

Comment: Add the code you tried to your question.

Comment: I'm asking about a best practice here, my code is irrelevant. Someone is creating a PDF form using Acrobat and I parse the fields names, which is a trivial code but doesn't seem like a valid practice to do.

Comment: What kind of additional information do you want to store in that field? Is that information static, or can it change depending on the field value?

Comment: I want to store a static string such as: groupId12_Title1_Subtitle  which I can later parse using iTextSharp (its like metadata for that field).

Comment: I want to store a static string such as: groupId12_Title1_Subtitle which I can later fetch using iTextSharp and parse using C# (its like metadata for that field).

Comment: You can store an extra entry in the field dictionary using a second class name for the entry's key. Later when you retrieve the field dictionary, you can look for an entry with that key. (I'm not posting any code because code is irrelevant in the context of your question. You are only asking for best practice.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but as I said, someone is preparing the PDF form manually using Adobe software. Later I take that form and parse it. The storing of the extra entry is not done programmatically. Where exactly should he store that info? We tried to store it inside the "Default value" (in the properties window of a specific field) but could not reach it from C#..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments to my questions above, and because I could not find a place to store metadata inside a pdf field, I finally used the following approach which i find the easiest:

1. In Acrobat DC pro I create a visible Text field and name it "Input_1".
2. I then create another field, name it: "Info_1", set it to Hidden (in the
   field properties), and set its Default Value to the MetaData I need to store
   (I can, for example store a Json string there: { group:1, title:'myTitle',
   moreInfo: 'some more info' }.
3. So, for each input field I create a hidden field with the same Id(number)
   and store additional info in its Default Value.
4. Save the PDF document.
5. Using iTextSharp, I retrieve the Form Fields using:

   ```
   PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filePath);
   AcroFields formFields = reader.AcroFields;
   foreach (KeyValuePair <string, AcroFields.Item> kvp in formFields.Fields)
   {
     string fieldName = kvp.Key;
     string fieldId = fieldName.Split('_')[1];
     string fieldInfo = formFields.GetField("Info_"+fieldId);
     string fieldType = formFields.GetFieldType(fieldName);
     // Now i can parse the fieldInfo string as I wish and store all info
     // in the Database
   }
   ```